# jQuery validation plugin and Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for my js form validation. I am also using Bootstrap 4. I've found that I needed to modify `errorPlacement`, `highlight`, and `unhighlight` to make it so that the validation errors properly show up in the BS4 style.

```
$('#login-form').validate({
    rules: {
        login_username: {
            required: true
        },
        login_password: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
        element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        neou_cms.remove_error_messages();
        var username = form.elements['login_username'].value;
        var password = CryptoJS.SHA512(form.elements['login_password'].value).toString();
        login.login_user(username, password);
    }
});
```

Thus for every function I find myself repeating those properties. Is there a way of "extending" the validation library so that I don't have to repeat the `errorPlacement`, `highlight`, and `unhighlight` code every time I use validate?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solution:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
        element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The set defaults as discribed will work on bootstrap 4 with the following :

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element) {
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'label label-danger',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

dont forget to add the class class="form-control" to the input field. 
The only thing i was not able to find is how to get the input field colored red when it has an error or green when its ok. Maybe any can add that option  to my answer ?

Comment: i've already found a solution about a few months ago. it is essentially the same.

Comment: WRT green colouring if ok: this chaining should do that: `jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid')`

Answer (score 8):

above an indicator solution didn't have the desired input spacing with the error label, use the code below and see the most pleasant result

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    onfocusout: function (e) {
        this.element(e);
    },
    onkeyup: false,

    highlight: function (element) {
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid');
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('is-valid');
    },

    errorElement: 'div',
    errorClass: 'invalid-feedback',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group-prepend').length) {
            $(element).siblings(".invalid-feedback").append(error);
            //error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lots.

Comment: Far closer than the accepted answer, even today on Bootstrap 5