# In ASP.NET MVC razor view ValidationMessageFor does not validate the input type text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC project and and in my razor view I have below input part:

```
   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div style="margin-right: 100px; margin-left: 100px">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" class="form-control required" placeholder="MobileNumber">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

and I referenced below jquery validations in my layout.cshtml:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I do not want to use HTML Helper instead of input type text. Why the ValidationMessageFor does not validate the input type text?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: When you are stating it doesn't validate, is that on key entry, or on submitting the form, Also have you initialised the form in jquey i.e $('form').validate();

Comment: Hello, yes this is right. It solved my problem. But how can I change the error text?

Comment: No wrries, added an answer below, please upvote if this helps :)

Comment: @Mostafa If you are using data annotations,error text you will be given in Model. change it there like `[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter mobile Number")]`

Comment: `class="form-control required"` replace by `class="form-control"  required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the libraries is not enough you to initialize and tell form validator which form you want to validate using $('form').validate(); Apply that to your scripts and then you shoudl start to see errors

in order to get a custom message you can use this snippet (many thanks to @Alex for this on from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159649/jquery-validation-plugin-and-bootstrap-4)) [Here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) si reference to rules as well.

```
$('form').validate({
   rules: {
      Mobile: //..imlement rule here
   },
   messages: {
     Mobile: "This is not a valid mobile or something..."
   }
})

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
        element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
});
```